# For $n>3$ show that the integers $n$, $n+2$, and $n+4$ cannot all be prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Okay so the solution I am given states that the division algorithm $\implies p=3k+1$ or $p=3k+2$ for some $k \in Z$ and $p \neq 3$.

Can anyone explain why $p$ has to be $3k+1$ or $3k+2$? I can't really figure out where its coming from.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by $p$, since you didn't define it anywhere. Hint: Show that one of the numbers must be a multiple of 3. What prime numbers do you know that are multiples of 3?

Comment: Thats where Im confused, how do you show that one of n, n+2, or n+4 is a multiple of three? Is it because every third integer is a multiple of three? I think thats the core of my question, how do I know that n, n+2, and n+4 has the from using 3q+r under the division algorithm?

Comment: (Are you familiar with modular arithmetic?) If $ n\equiv 0 \pmod {3}$ we are done. If $n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ then $n+2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3} $. If $n \equiv 2 \pmod{3} $ then $n+4 \equiv 0 \pmod {3}$.

Comment: Yes I do know modular arithmetic and that makes complete sense when you phrase it that way. Thanks!

Comment: The reason for my first question, is that if you say $n= 3k$ or $n=3k+1$ or $n=3k+2$, that's essentially what my 2nd comment says. So you might want to review if the $p$ should have been an $n$ instead.

Answer (score 3):

Every number $n$ can be written in one and only one of the following forms:

- $n = 3k$
- $n = 3k + 1$
- $n = 3k + 2$

where $k$ is some integer. If $p$ is prime, then the only numbers dividing $p$ are $1$ and $p$. If $p\neq 3$, is there any way that prime $p$ can be a multiple of $3$? That is, can it be the case that $p$ is prime AND $p = 3k$?

What cases of the three cases above, then, must we rule out?

Comment: Let me know if you need any additional clarification about the rest of the proof/solution you're reading.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $n$ is prime. Then $n$ cannot have the form $n = 3k$ (else $3$ would be a factor). Thus you have either $n = 3k + 1$ or $n = 3k + 2$. In the first case you have that $n + 2 = 3k + 3 = 3(k + 1)$, in the second one you have that $n + 4 = 3k + 6 = 3(k + 2)$. Thus you can never have $n$, $n+1$ and $n+2$ primes at the same time.

Comment: Except when $n = 3$ :)

Comment: He specifies: "(...) else 3 would be a factor"

Comment: @Stahl: In the title you have the assumption $n > 3$

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Ah, when I looked at the question/answer, I only saw him asking why primes were $1$ or $2$ mod $3$. My mistake! :P